# Using AFNetworking _convertJSONString keeps allocated

Tags: ios, memory-management, afnetworking, allocation, nsjsonserialization

I'm using AFNetworking, and I encountered a problem when I was calling a POST with JSON. I'm uploading several images in base64, and I noticed that even if I uploaded everything, _convertJSONString, or something related, is still in memory. Should be the JSON conversion applied by AFNetworking when I created the NSURLRequest, that actually should be released. I don't know if I'm missing something, but it's a weird behavior.

This is an example of how I'm implementing the request inside my client:

```
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [self requestWithMethod:@"POST" path:path parameters:params];
AFJSONRequestOperation *operation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
        success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
            completionBlock(JSON, response, nil);
        failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
            completionBlock(nil, response, error);
        }];

[self enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];
```

And this is the line where Instrument says the allocation comes from:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wassign-enum"
                    [request setHTTPBody:[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:parameters options:0 error:&error]];
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

that's part of:

```
- (NSMutableURLRequest *)requestWithMethod:(NSString *)method
                                      path:(NSString *)path
                                parameters:(NSDictionary *)parameters
```

in AFHTTPClient.m

Thank you in advance for any help, or solution.

**FIRST WORKAROUND**

I've found that the NSURLRequest's content inside AFURLConnectionOperation is not completely released when the operation is finished, and this causes a leak. 
Setting `self.request = nil` inside `- (void)finish` method solves the problem.
This is just a workaround, but I cannot currently find another way.

Comment: Yes you should release it , once you are done with it and it is no more required.

Comment: @Abhishek is mistaken. Manual memory management is unnecessary with ARC.

Comment: The JSON object is probably be being held by another object in a circular reference. Take your eyes off AFNetworking and see what else is leaking; you'll probably find it quickly.

Comment: I used the code above, nothing else. I tried everything I could, but the only thing that worked was setting the request as nil inside AFNetworking. Do you have any idea of how I could solve in another way?

Answer (score -1):

This is not an issue. Objects may be relatively long-lived in memory, without being a leak.

Don't worry about it.

Comment: I gotta worry because the app is running out of memory for this leak. If you have an idea of how I could solve it without touching AFNetworking, please tell me. I would really like to know where is my mistake. Thanks